# Plotting cosine with Python

Tags: python

I plot a cosine sampled at 400 points in the interval -5 .. +5 using python for n=1..4:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

for n in range(1,5):
    x = numpy.linspace(-5,5,num=400)
    series = numpy.cos(1e4/n*x)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(series)
```

But for n = 3 the plot looks not like a cosine which I think is due to sampling error. How can I achieve a smooth cosine plot with constant samples for different frequencies (i.e. different n)?

Comment: Where is `n` defined?

Comment: Ups, I edited my code; n is the loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your calculation to `series = numpy.cos(2*numpy.pi/n*x)`.

Multiplying by `1e4` means you have fewer than 2 points per cycle of your cosine, thus causing [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

Comment: Now I think that also the plot function of python cannot handle with only two points hence causing display errors.